# R Aggregate FUN=head

Tags: r, aggregate

I would like to aggregate a table (tab) by two columns (sequence and program) to get the top row of samplesize (FUN=head).

```
sq <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1) 
prog<- c('A','A','B','B','C','C') 
ss <- c(47,47,28,28,47,47) 
tab<- data.frame(sq,prog,ss)
```

Aggregate is giving me an odd result in that if the sample size is the same for a DIFFERENT combination of sequence and program- it omits it.

```
agg  <- aggregate(cbind(sq,prog) ~ ss, data = tab, FUN=head,1,na.rm=TRUE)
```

I'm confused why this is occurring and why it is changing the program to a numerical sequence when it is text (A,B,C).

Comment: Your aggregation is wrong: `agg  <- aggregate(ss ~ sq + prog, data = tab, FUN=head,1,na.rm=TRUE)`

Answer (score 2):

It's because by default, `data.frame` creates a factor from character columns. You need:

```
tab <- data.frame(sq, prog, ss, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

EDIT: I personally find the `dplyr` package very intuitive. For your result, I'd use:

```
library(dplyr)
tab %>%
  group_by(sq, prog) %>% 
  filter(row_number() == 1)
```

Comment: well this answers why it is giving me numbers instead of the letters in the aggregated table.  However, the main problem still persists:  it omits the records where sample size might be the same for a different combination of sequence and program?

Comment: Ok, I hadn't realised. I've now edited my answer accordingly.