# R aggregate turns strings into numbers. Why does this happen and how can I avoid it?

Tags: r

Why does this code print only numbers to the console? How can I get a list with names 1 through 13 and contents a,n ; b,o; et cetera?

`aggregate(letters, by = data.frame(rep(1:13, 2)), head, simplify = F)`

I'm using R 3.5.1.

I haven't found a duplicate yet. Here is what I have found so far on similar topics.

A similar but not identical question:

[R Aggregate FUN=head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48588890/r-aggregate-fun-head)

An apparently similar question that is actually about aggregating numbers:

[R: Aggregate character strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37180479/r-aggregate-character-strings)

Answer (score 1):

`letters` is coerced to a dataframe. It becomes a factor. Factors are stored as integers in R. If the levels are lost somewhere, they often start to just look like integers. Try this instead:

`aggregate(data.frame(letters, stringsAsFactors = F), by = data.frame(rep(1:13, 2)), head, simplify = F)`

Comment: The documentation says "If simplify is true, summaries are simplified to vectors or matrices if they have a common length of one or greater than one, respectively; otherwise, lists of summary results according to subsets are obtained." The result of this command is a list, technically, but it is not a list according to subsets because it has length 2 rather than the expected length of 13. This answer would be better if it could explain that as well.

Comment: Actually, the result does contain a list of length 13. It is the second column of the returned dataframe.